# Find the diametre of the well

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm stuck in solving this problem.

> Below, there is a well and $2$ sticks are thrown inside.The distance from the intersection of the rods to the bottom of the well is $1 m$ .What is the diametre of the well?

I think, this is not possible to find the diametre. Am I right?

[image]

Comment: @Maths How can I show missing details?

Comment: I'm asking you. Do you not have an actual diagram or is this all you have? Do you not have a picture of the problem sheet/ homework you were given?

Comment: @Maths I just did the text translation. I drew the picture myself.

Comment: @Beginner Just to clarify: Is $AB = 38, DC = 28, OK = 18$?

Comment: This is what's confusing me @TobyMak He says the intersection is 1m but that looks like 18

Comment: @TobyMak from the question, I think they're 3, 2 and 1 m respectively. All the 8s are some kind of parts of the unit

Comment: @TobyMak hmmm.It is interesting. Is it possible to find the diametre for $38,28,18 ?$

Comment: @Beginner I'll try to solve the original problem first. Before that, I need to know what $AB, DC$ and $OK$ are!

Comment: As far as I understand, the question is missing. I'm gonna tell that to the teacher.

Comment: Try here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1456516/420432

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_ladders_problem) is your friend.

Comment: @TobyMak There is no solution for 18, 28 and 38. But there is one for 1,2 and 3

Comment: @nickgard Looking at the answer there, the problem seems to be trivial but it's not, as demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce $x=AD$, $y=BC$ and $d=AC$. We have some obvious relations coming from similar triangles:

$$\frac{OK}{x}=\frac{KC}{d}\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{OK}{y}=\frac{AK}{d}\tag{2}$$

Add (1) and (2) and you get:

$$OK\left(\frac 1x+\frac 1y\right)=\frac{AK+KC}{d}=\frac dd$$

$$OK\left(\frac 1x+\frac 1y\right)=1\tag{3}$$

Using Pitagora:

$$d^2+x^2={DC}^2\tag{4}$$

$$d^2+y^2={AB}^2\tag{5}$$

Now you have a system of 3 equations ((3), (4), (5)) with three unknowns ($x$, $y$, $d$), with $d$ being the only "interesting" one. From (4) and (5) you get:

$$x=\sqrt{DC^2-d^2}$$

$$y=\sqrt{AB^2-d^2}$$

Replace this into (3) and you will obtain a single equation with a single unknown value:

$$\frac {1}{\sqrt{DC^2-d^2}}+\frac {1}{\sqrt{AB^2-d^2}}=\frac1{OK}\tag{6}$$

For $AB=3$, $DC=2$, $OK=1$, the equation (6) becomes:

$$\frac {1}{\sqrt{4-d^2}}+\frac {1}{\sqrt{9-d^2}}=1$$

...or if you introduce substitution $z=d^2$:

$$\frac {1}{\sqrt{4-z}}+\frac {1}{\sqrt{9-z}}=1$$

This looks like a simple equation to solve but it's not. You'll have to square it twice to get rid of the roots and you will end up with an equation of 4-th degree:

$$z^4-22 z^3+163 z^2-454 z+385=0$$

It can be solved analytically and of four solutions only one is a real, positive number that satisfies the original equation. But that number is ugly, I mean VERY UGLY and I am not going to reproduce it here in full. The approximate value is:

$$z=d^2=1.51582 \implies d=1.23119$$

I have also solved the problem in a slightly different way using trigonometry but it still leads to equation (6).

**EDIT**

If you use different values (as suggested in some comments): $AB=38$, $DC=28$, $OK=18$, the equation (6) becomes:

$$\frac {1}{\sqrt{28^2-d^2}}+\frac {1}{\sqrt{38^2-d^2}}=\frac1{18}$$

...and Mathematica says that it has no real positive solutions for $d$.

Comment: Fantastic solution. You mean, the question is correct?

Comment: @Beginner Yes, the question is correct.

Comment: We have $2$ positive real roots. WA says.

Comment: You are **not** right: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+1%2FSqrt%5B28%5E2-x%5E2%5D+%2B+1%2FSqrt%5B38%5E2-x%5E2%5D%3D1%2F18 

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+1%2FSqrt%5B2%5E2-x%5E2%5D+%2B+1%2FSqrt%5B3%5E2-x%5E2%5D%3D1%2F1

Comment: I mean Yout quartic equation

Comment: @Beginner When you square an equation to get rid of the roots, it does not mean that the original and the squared equations are equivalent (have same solutions). Typical example: equation $\sqrt{x}=-1$ has no solutions. When you square it you get $x=1$. Squaring is allowed but all solutions obtained after that have to be checked against the original equation. So you are right, my quartic equation has two real solutions but only one satisfies the original equation (the one that I mentioned).

Comment: I think, without a computer (WA and etc.) it is not possible to do so..

Comment: @Beginner As you probably now, quartic equations have analytical solution. So you can solve every single quartic equation by hand. It's just that the process is long and boring. Computer does the same thing, only faster and never gets bored :)

Comment: I mean,To find out that the root we found has the original equation, we need to write the answer instead. It may be impossible to determine the root we found by the manual procedure.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think the relations (i) and (ii) should be sufficient to solve for $\theta$ and $\phi$ and hence $AC$.

(i) would give : $2\cos\theta = 3\cos\phi$

and (ii) : $2\sin\theta + 3\sin\phi = 6\sin\theta \sin\phi$

solving these would give the answer.